# How to start Spring Boot server in @BeforeClass of junit

Tags: junit, spring-boot, integration-testing

We need to use Spring Boot in our project for testing only at present. The Spring app configuration and test app configuration are as below:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@DirtiesContext
public abstract class TestApplicationContext {
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Now we need to ensure the Spring Boot server starts in `@BeforeClass` so that a client can connect to it before any tests run. How do I enable the Spring Boot server to run this way? Removing `@SpringapplicationConfiguration` and manually starting the server in `@BeforeClass` like this does not work (it says `ContextLoader is NULL`). Can someone point out how to achieve this?

```
public class TestClass extends TestApplicationContext {
    ...
    ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext;
    @Beforeclass
    public void setup() {
        appContext = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, "");
        ...  
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why are you rolling your own... The `IntegrationTest` already takes care of starting your app. What is it that you cannot do when Spring Boot takes care of bootstrapping the application?

Comment: All your annotations on the test class are redundant or in error once you remove the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`. What Marten said: why do you want to do that?